# Apps location in Django using pinax

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pinax

Maybe this is a silly question, but I'm new to all of this and I could use some help. I recently just started a new django project using pinax. Specifically, it's the pinax accounts project for user sign-ins.  When I look at my project folder, it doesn't include any apps. I've noticed that all of my apps are stored in virtualenv/Lib/site-packages...

Why is it that the apps for my project are stored here? Does it make more sense to move them into my actual project folder instead of working out of the virtual machine folder? So I guess my question is: when working in a virtual machine, are all apps, etc stored in the virtual machine folder as apposed to the project folder? And why?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, It has nothing to do with `pinax` in particular. I'm no expert, and don't take my word for it, but that's how I see it. The namespacing of the package/app is based on what actually using this package/app. For example, your project is based on Django, right? which is using Python, which is using whole bunch of other packages. Maybe some other project of yours will use Python as well. What's going to happen if you would want to delete your project, but wait you already put python in there or something else reusable. Do I make sense to you?

Comment: Hi @DejaVu, that makes sense. It's done this way so that the apps can be used across different projects. Do I have to copy the app into my project for clarity?

Comment: That depends. Look at the "scope" of your app. If its a django app and its working with very particular(current project) DB - I would have it namespaced **exclusively** within the project. If your app is recyclable and might be used in several projects - you might want to consider it to be stored somewhere else. Imagine if you use this(recyclable) app across 3 different projects and you developed a new feature - you will have to update all 3 of them separately, see my point?

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense :)